# Spark: TreeAgregate at IDF is taking ages

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.6.1, and I have a DataFrame as follow:

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|ID         |dateTime             |title                          |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|809907895  |2017-01-21 23:00:01.0|                               |
|1889481973 |2017-01-21 23:00:06.0|Man charged with murder of ... |
|979847722  |2017-01-21 23:00:09.0|Munster cruise to home Cham... |
|18894819734|2017-01-21 23:00:11.0|Man charged with murder of ... |
|17508023137|2017-01-21 23:00:15.0|Emily Ratajkowski hits the ... |
|10321187627|2017-01-21 23:00:17.0|Gardai urge public to remai... |
|979847722  |2017-01-21 23:00:19.0|Sport                          |
|19338946129|2017-01-21 23:00:33.0|                               |
|979847722  |2017-01-21 23:00:35.0|Rassie Erasmus reveals the ... |
|1836742863 |2017-01-21 23:00:49.0|NAMA sold flats which could... |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I am doing the following operation:

```
val aggDF = df.groupBy($"ID")
              .agg(concat_ws(" ", collect_list($"title")) as "titlesText")
```

Then on `aggDF` DataFrame, I am fitting a pipeline that extracts TFIDF feature from `titlesText` column (by applying `tokenizer`, `stopWordRemover`, `HashingTF` then `IDF`).

When I call the `pipline.fit(aggDF)` the code reaches a stage `treeAggregate at IDF.scala:54` (I can see that on the UI), and then it gets stuck there, without any progress, without any error, I wait very long time without any progress and no helpful information on UI.

Here is an example of what I see in the UI (nothing changes for very long time):

[image]

- What are the possible reasons of that?
- How to track and debug such problems?
- Is there any other way to extract the same feature?

Comment: I am guessing your data is larger than the table above? It looks there is a 2.7GB shuffle write, which can take quite a while depending on the number of partitions, etc.

Comment: Yes indeed, the data is much bigger than the example. I just left the partitioning as it is in the default. Changing the parting could make things better?

Comment: @Derek_M Could increasing the number of partitions cause more computation time because of the shuffling between partitions? Is there a heuristic for setting partition size depending on the level of parallelism (Executors, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify [a maximum number of features in your HashingTF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF@numFeatures:org.apache.spark.ml.param.IntParam)?

Because the amount of data the IDF has to deal with will be proportional to the number of features produced by HashingTF and it will most likely have to spill on disk for very large amounts which wastes time.

Comment: Yes, I chose it to be equal to 500, is it that large?

Comment: No, that's nothing, for large vocabularies this won't be enough, I'd suggest not setting it and inspecting the logs to see how large your hash table naturally is.

For example, I originally had ~262k entries after HashingTF and I reduced that to 50k.